# Issue with session and Curl Requests

Tags: php, session, curl

I'm having some issues with sessions in PHP.

I have a script that is posting information from srv1.domain.com to srv2.domain.com where it is processed.

I've set-up session_set_cookie like the following.

```
session_set_cookie_params (0, '/', '.domain.com', false, true);
session_name('mysession');
session_start();
```

On srv2.domain.com the script processes the data and stores some session information in

```
$_SESSION['example']
```

I then perform a curl request to the same server **srv2.domain.com/convert.php** how-ever when I get there and print out the session **$_SESSION['example']** is different. If I print the **$_SESSION['example']** before and after the curl request it's correct.

I have a cookie with the PHPSESSID that I'm passing to the curl request and loading on convert.php before calling session start.

```
session_id($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
```

I'm not sure whats going on but I've been trying to figure this out for the past few hours. Very frustrating.

**Update**

I might add that srv1.domain.com is a reverse proxy to srv2.domain.com.

Comment: PHP sessions are file-based by default, and LOCAL to the specific server that the session was created. on. Just because you may be setting the same ID on the two servers doesn't magically make the contents of each server's session file get shared between the two of them. The **ONLY** thing in common between those two sessions will be their IDs, and a value stored in the session  on srv1 will not exist on srv2, and vice versa.

Comment: @MarcB I should say that server 1 and server 2 are the same server and the same file paths. Just one is being accessed via reverse proxy. Does this mean that the session is being stored on the server that is serving the reverse proxy request?

Comment: what kind of reverse proxy? at the apache level?  or you have a php script which then does a `curl` or whatever on its own?

Comment: it's configured in apache virtual hosts.